# Native View Presenting a React Native View

Tags: ios, view, react-native

Does anyone know how I can have a native UIViewController present or push a React Native view, and go back and forth between the two?

If possible, I'd like to load the React Native view inside a UIViewController so I can retain my navigation bar, but use the React Native view.

I've been reading the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html), but I have not been able to find anything that works.

I've tried a combination of this:

```
//  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:nil launchOptions:nil];
//  RCTRootView *reactView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"My Test" initialProperties:nil];

    NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
    RCTRootView *reactView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                         moduleName:@"My Test"
                                                  initialProperties:nil
                                                      launchOptions:nil];

    reactView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:reactView];
```

I'm not quite sure I understand how it knows what .js React file I want it to use, or  how I specify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have this kind of approach working you'll at least need:

1. Access to a bridge that all your `RCTRootView`s can share. If you want each root view to load a different RN component from the same bundle - they need to share the same`RCTBridge`
2. A `UIViewController` that its view is a `RCTRootView`. You can then use this view controller as the root of a navigation controller, show it modally etc. like you've already tried to do.

**Let's take a look at a very simplistic example implementation of this idea.**

#### 1. An object that holds the shared bridge

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTBridge.h"

@interface ReactBridgeManager : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) RCTBridge *bridge;
-(instancetype)initWithBundleURL:(NSURL *)bundleURL launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ReactBridgeManager.h"

@interface ReactBridgeManager () <RCTBridgeDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RCTBridge *bridge;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *bundleURL;
@end

@implementation ReactBridgeManager

- (instancetype)initWithBundleURL:(NSURL *)bundleURL launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    self.bundleURL = bundleURL;
    self.bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  }
  return self;
}

#pragma mark - RCTBridgeDelegate methods

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return self.bundleURL;
}

@end
```

#### 2. A view controller that controls a react root view

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RCTBridge.h"

@interface ReactViewController : UIViewController
- (instancetype)initWithBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge moduleName:(NSString*)moduleName initialProps:(NSDictionary*)initialProps;
@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "ReactViewController.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation ReactViewController

- (instancetype)initWithBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge moduleName:(NSString*)moduleName initialProps:(NSDictionary*)initialProps
{
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {
    self.view = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:moduleName initialProperties:initialProps];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

#### 3. Usage example

You can now create instances of `ReactViewController` where necessary with your react component name (this is a component that was registered in RN `AppRegistry` on the JS side) and push it into your native navigation stack, show it as a modal, etc.

```
//when your app is initialized, create the bridge manager and hold a reference to it.
ReactBridgeManager *bridgeManager = [[ReactBridgeManager alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

//create a view controller that's controlling a react root view
ReactViewController *reactViewController = [[ReactViewController alloc] initWithBridge:bridgeManager.bridge moduleName:@"MyComponent" initialProps:nil];
```

#### Taking it to the next level

You can take a look at [React Native Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) which basically uses the same concept to allow a fully native navigation solution for react-native apps. Disclaimer: I'm part of the team that develops this package :)

Comment: Okay, I did all this and it is working well. However, I am still confused on what jsCodeLocation should point to. Any ideas? I am using: NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"/src/components/" fallbackResource:nil];
 
 //when your app is initialized, create the bridge manager and hold a reference to it.
 self.bridgeManager = [[ReactBridgeManager alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

Comment: jsCodeLocation should be the same as for any RN project, use `jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];`

Comment: @Artal Can you please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620105/dismiss-a-view-controller-from-react-native

Comment: I believe this should be `jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.js" fallbackResource:nil];` (i.e. use index.js instead of index.ios)