# React Native iOS - Network Request Failed

Tags: ios, react-native

I am integrating React Native into an existing iOS project. I am running into some issues and I cannot get past them. I've been trying to resolve this for days.

I am getting a 'Network Request Failed' error when I launch my app (simulator and physical device). Does anyone know why I am getting this network error? I think my app is setup correctly for React Native, but it will not get past this network error. I've tried so many things.

My Info.plist has this in it:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

I've added a *Bundle React Native code and images* script to my *Build Phases*:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh
```

I setup my jsBundleUrl like this:

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

The root of my project contains a file index.ios.js which registers the Component that I'm trying to load.

I setup my RCTRootView like this:

```
self.reactView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:moduleName initialProperties:initialProps];

self.reactView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.reactView];
```

The Bridge is setup as defined in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193418/native-view-presenting-a-react-native-view).

Is there something I'm missing in the way the app connects to the wifi network and then attempts to hit my machine? I'm really lost at this point.

The console is printing this out constantly (every second):

```
nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 43 Connection has no connected handler
```

Here is a screenshot of the error. I get this on simulators and physical devices.
[image]

Comment: What's the call stack for the failed network request? Is it coming from React or from your code?

Comment: @YSK Not sure. I updated the question.

Comment: @YSK Seems like it's coming from React.